# Can't expose custom field to REST API

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, rest-api

As far as I can tell, the following code should make the `video` custom field of my CPT `project` available through REST API. Yet the custom field is still not exposed.

Why not?

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_featured_video');

function register_featured_video() {
    register_rest_field(
    'project',
    'video',
    array(
      'get_callback'    => 'get_featured_video',
      'update_callback' => null,
      'schema'          => null,
      )
    );
}

function get_featured_video($object) {   
  $post_id = $object['id']; 
  return get_post_meta($post_id); 
}
```

EDIT:
My current `functions.php`: https://pastecode.dev/s/uIkZtiqkZn

Object returned through REST API:
[image]

Comment: When you created the CPT with `register_post_type` did you set `'show_in_rest' => true`?

Comment: 1. Are you sure that `$post_id` gets a value? (It's possible that `$object['id']` should be `$object['ID']`.) 2. [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) called without a `$key` parameter will return *all* of a post's metadata; is that your intent?

Comment: @PatJ 1. I'd like to check that but how? I can echo stuff from the "root" of `function.php` but not from inside functions like `register_featured_video()` or `get_featured_video()`.

Comment: You could use [`error_log()`](https://php.net/error_log) to print it to your error log, if you've got [debugging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) enabled. (By default the error log would be `/wp-content/debug.log` if `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is `true`.)

Comment: Just added the following my `wp-config.php`: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` but I still don't see `debug.log` file appearing anywhere in my folder tree after reloading my site's page many times. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried register_post_meta( 'project', 'video', array( 'show_in_rest' => true ) );

Comment: @birgire I just added it to my `functions.php` using `https://gist.github.com/MjHead/43d1f8a09a88548dc813539b7f7a8619` as a reference. Doesn't add anything to the response from REST endpoint. I don't understand why something so elemental isn't built-in by now or why they didn't add custom fields in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/. In any case, I'm still unable to retrieve my custom field through REST API :/

Comment: Does your cpt support custom fields in register_post_type ?

Comment: Surprisingly, nope. Which makes me wonder why on earth was I still able to use custom fields in my CPT.. Anyway I just enabled it but I still don't see my custom field returned when querying the REST endpoint.

Comment: works for me, what is your updated current code for setting up cpt and meta ?

Comment: @birgire here's the current version of my entire `functions.php`: https://pastecode.dev/s/uIkZtiqkZn

Comment: What happens when you place register_post_meta( 'project', 'video', array( 'show_in_rest' => true ) ); just under the register_post_type(...) line?

Comment: Just did, same result I'm afraid. I added a screenshot of the object currently returned btw.

Comment: ps: my suggestions assumed the wp-json/wp/v2/project endpoint ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is how you register the rest routes and how you return data for the single project endpoint.

When you register the route and the callback like this.

```
function single_project($data) {
    $post_ID = $data['id'];
    return get_post($post_ID);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'project/v1', 'post/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'single_project',
        'args' => ['id']
    ));
});
```

You'll just get the default fields the `WP_Post`object has. The data does not get processed the same way as regular posts do. This means that `register_rest_field()` does not have a chance to add the additional field to the response.

If you did something like

```
class WP_REST_Projects_Controller extends WP_REST_Posts_Controller {
    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route( 'project/v1', 'post/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'            => array( $this, 'get_item' ),
            'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_item_permissions_check' ),
            'args'                => [],
        ));
    }
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    (new WP_REST_Projects_Controller('project'))->register_routes();
});
```

then the additional field would get added to the response, as the global variable which `register_rest_field()` affects is used inside `WP_REST_Controller` which `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` extends. *Inside `get_additional_fields()` method to be specific.*

You should either extend the controller class and override it as needed or modify the `single_project()` callback to return additional fields along the post fields.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works in the sense that I know see my custom field returned inside the object which is great! The only thing is that it returns not just the post requested but all posts. How to fix that, and how should this code integrate with the rest of my route declarations?

Comment: @drake035 Sorry about that, I had a copy-paste error on the above class example. The callbacks were supposed to be in singular form, not plural. I fixed the example.

Comment: I'll try to have another look at your code tomorrow for suggestions on how to integrate the controller with the other route declarations. You can also have a look at the class docs, if you want to give it a go yourself https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/#methods

Comment: thanks. I think I can just use your code for the single endpoint, and keep my definitions for the other endpoints. I'm bewildered though: isn't the desire to get custom fields through REST API extremely common, that is, isn't this feature super basic? If so, why does it require such convoluted workaround? And why is there so few threads/articles about it? I really can't understand this.

Comment: @drake035 Ok, do post another question, if you have further questions regarding the other endpoints. `register_rest_field()` is the right tool for the job when you're working with the default WP post/page endpoints. In a case like this where you define custom endpoints and callbacks, then you need to decide and explicitly define the schema, how data is retrieved and handled, etc. yourself and can't rely too much on filters as the callback spits out exactly, and only, what you tell it to. If on the other hand you extend the default controllers, then you can piggyback WP and utilize the filters.

Comment: OK, thank you very much @AnttiKoskinen!